# haskell call function of certain instance

Tags: haskell

I have a class :

```
> class Binaer a where
>   binaer_zu_a :: String -> a
```

And two instances:

```
> instance Binaer Integer where
>   binaer_zu_a b = 3

> instance Binaer Bool where
>   binaer_zu_a b = True
```

So the input to he function binaer_zu_a is always a string, but how do I have to call the function so that the function "knows" which of them it should execute?

If I try to call it like `binaer_zu_a :: Bool "01"` for example I ge an`ERROR - Syntax error in input (unexpected string literal)`

So how do I need to call that function?

Comment: If you annotate the function, you need to do so with a function type: `(binaer_zu_a :: String -> Bool) "True"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify the type argument like this

```
> (binaer_zu_a "b") :: Integer
3
> (binaer_zu_a "b") :: Bool
True
```

Answer (score 3):

With the `TypeApplications` extension, you can specify the type (or rather, an expression representing the type) as the first argument.

```
> :set -XTypeApplications
> binaer_zu_a @Bool "True"
True
```